# How many phone numbers can you make with the following rules?

Tags: combinatorics

It includes of 7 digits, the first digit is 4, the phone number doesn't hold any 0 and it has exactly 3 pieces of the number 2.

I assume that the solution is:$9^3$, is that true?

Comment: How is this a soft question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) You have not taken into consideration **where** the $2$'s occur. Their locations can be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.

(ii) The remaining digits are non-$2$ (and non-$0$), so they can be chosen in $8^3$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

The first digit is $4$, thus we have another $6$ digits to place that are between $1$ and $9$. $3$ are the digit $2$, hence we need to choose $3$ places for 2 $\displaystyle {6 \choose 3}$. The other $3$ digits can be $1$ or number between $3$ and $9$, hence $8^3$. At total we have $\displaystyle {6\choose 3}\cdot{8^3}=10240$.

Comment: Many thank this example was pretty trivial, but I couldn't solve it in the morning...